# Scala compile warning with pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

I have an Akka Actor that has the following case pattern match check in its receive method as below:

```
def receive = {
  case x: (String, ListBuffer[String]) if(x._2.size >= 0) => {
  .....
  .....
}
```

When I compile, I get to see the following compiler warnings:

```
warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern (String, scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]) 
is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure)
```

Any clues as to how I could get rid of them? I do not want to set the compiler settings to ignore these warnings, but I do not see a reason why the compiler issues a warning?

Comment: Scala only sees from x during runtime that it is a Tuple2, so if a Tuple2 comes with different type parameters, that might be a real problem there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One little trick I like to use for this problem is type aliasing.

```
type MyBuffer = ListBuffer[String]

//...

def receive = {
  case x: (String, MyBuffer) if(x._2.size >= 0) => {
  //.....
  //.....
}
```

Comment: Except this doesn't resolve the actual problem at all.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Try it. The compiler will NOT throw the warning. He merely wants the warnings to go away.

Comment: The issue is that he didn't see the reason for the warning, see the last sentence of the question.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Sure, I don't address the real issue or answer his last question.  But if it truly is a "don't care", then this is another handy trick to get around it.  Thanks for clearing it up. :)

Comment: I tried using a type alias, but the warning is still there!

Comment: Really? I'm surprised. I use it all the time. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the JVM's type erasure. At runtime, the JVM only sees `ListBuffer[Any]`. Static type information of generics is lost. If you don't care about the generic type of the ListBuffer, you can change the pattern match to:

```
case x: (String, ListBuffer[_]) if(x._2.size >= 0) =>
```

Comment: This would mean that I have to cast x._2 to a ListBuffer[String] before I could use it. Not so ideal!